# Installing AIR runtime and AIR application in own click

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have AIR application that i have created. One of my customers wants me to give him a CD that will automatically install the application with computer that has no AIR runtime installed.

How can i create an automatic installer that can install the AIR runtime and my AIR application easily?

Thanks in advance,
Lior

Comment: http://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/deploying-air-application-with-air-runtimeredistributable-in-single-exe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With AIR 3 you can create an installer using Captive Runtime, which makes it so that your app no longer has a dependency to the AIR runtime.  That will probable be your easiest best option.  [More info](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader)

Additionally, you could sign up for a [redistribution license of Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/special/products/air/runtime_distribution1.html) which gives you permission to do that.  Along with that, I believe they offer instructions on how do a headless/invisible install of the AIR runtime. Then you'll have to create your own installer which will perform the headless AIR install along with your own AIR app.

Comment: +1 for Captive Runtime. It does significantly increase file size but on a CD that shouldn't matter.